# Сделать ссылку "начать конкурс" более заметной

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Почему кнопка "начать конкурс" такая скучная? Невзрачная. Черт поймешь, что этот текст вообще что-то делает. С точки зрения дизайна — вообще пустое место, подвешана одинокая строка в конце ответа. Начинается с маленькой буквы даже, как будто продолжает сообщение в вопросе, но без точки...

В общем, как мне кажется, она заслуживает хорошей перерисовки, редизайна если угодно. Чтоб при ховере вся переливалась всеми красками и было весело её нажимать.

А то сидят чуваки по 3к, 6к, 1321к репутации и ничего не хотят. А так хоть стимул будет щелкнуть на неё :D

Comment: Шта? К чему этот вопрос?

Comment: @Other если убрать радугу и единорогов из вопроса, то ситуация действительно имеет место быть. [Ответа пока нет.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287606/339911)

Comment: Один чувак с 14к [довольно часто](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin?tab=bounties&sort=offered) её тыкает. Дело-то не в дизайне. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin меценат! Может пожертвуете на улучшение дизайна ссылки? :)

Comment: @alexolut боюсь, разработчики не принимают такую валюту.

Comment: @NickVolynkin это-то и печально. Объявляешь конкурс на какой-нибудь FR, а тебе ноль внимания от девелоперов. Бесперспективняк.

Comment: Автор, расскажите лучше, почему вы хотите чтобы эту кнопку чаще жали? Недостаточно конкурсов открывается на сайте? Участники не «делятся» репутацией? Вполне допускаю, что такие проблемы могут быть. Но нужно как-то явно и аргументированно о них написать.

Comment: @alexolut кстати, плюсанул про цвет ссылки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin там уже появилась гипотеза, что это баг.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ты ведь не считаешь себя глупым? Ты же понял (пробиваясь через многочисленные рога единорогов) о чем речь? Конкретно: сделать заметнее и красивее кнопку "начать конкурс" - вот моё предложение.

Comment: @VostokSisters я вроде понял, а вы — нет. Вопрос: ЗАЧЕМ делать кнопку заметнее и красивее? Что, её не замечают? Она не приносит эстетического удовольствия? Не укладывается в общий графический стиль сайта? Если вы хотите, чтобы что-то поменялось, нужна цель, смысл нужен. Разработчики не будут делать радужную кнопку просто так.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, слушай, это предложение моё.  Предложение сделать её красивее, потому что мне не нравится, как она выглядит. Скучно. По-моему на невзрачную кнопку нажимают меньше чем на красивую. Если хочется и к этому пристать, то погугли, есть исследования на эту тему.

Comment: @VostokSisters, если тебе не нравится как выглядит кнопка, ты можешь стилизовать ее как угодно с помощью расширений для браузера, например [stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=ru)

Comment: @Grundy, ну тогда можно и скрипты самому писать на Tampermonkey, дали бы просто апи SO, и всё, делай что хочешь. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: @VostokSisters, такое апи так же существует: [api.stackexchange](https://api.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @VostokSisters держи друх https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Comment: @Grundy, ну так и закрыли бы Met'у, в чем проблема-то? Все сами могут всё накодить и настилизовать. Ты понял мой посыл.

Comment: @VostokSisters, нет, не понял. Ты говоришь, что _тебе_ не нравится вид кнопки. Я тебе дал варианты как стилизовать ее так, чтобы _тебе_ нравилась.

Comment: @Grundy, почему я просто не могу предложить стилизовать кнопочку на сайте, когда она действительно выглядит незаметной и неудобной (без сомнения) - для меня загадка.

Comment: @VostokSisters предложить-то можете, но чтобы у предложения был хоть малейший шанс стать реальностью, нужно описать, какая от этого будет польза.

Comment: @VostokSisters, почему не можешь? ты же именно это и сделал. Непонятно твое удивление тому, что кроме тебя это никому не нужно.

Comment: @Grundy, я сюда написал затем, чтобы поддержали те, кто также думает, что она не клёвая. И чтобы её изменили всем на радость.

Comment: @D-side, да красивее будет, елы палы :DDD Хочешь, чтобы деревьев побольше посадили около дома? А зачем тебе деревья, так уж сильно ощущаешь нехватку воздуха на земле? Нет. А вот во внешнем виде своего района ты наверняка заинтересован. Тут то же самое.

Comment: @VostokSisters, пока таких не нашлось. Ну а так как мета это публичное место, стоило быть готовым, что тут не только поддерживают любые идеи.

Comment: @VostokSisters _да красивее будет_ - понятие _красивее_ весьма растяжимое. Для всех по разному. Кому-то и сейчас кажется - верхом красоты и минимализма.

Comment: @VostokSisters "красивее" не аргумент, ибо субъективно. Мне нравится то, как StackExchange выглядит сейчас: аккуратно, минималистично, в глаза ничего не лезет и не отвлекает от того, что действительно важно. Вы хотите это сломать. Я против, потому и проголосовал соответствующе. И судя по рейтингу вопроса, таких как я много.

Comment: @D-side, в смысле? Причем тут весь SO? Я про кнопочку тут говорю.

Comment: @VostokSisters потому что эта кнопочка, внезапно, на SO!

Comment: @VostokSisters как у меня горит с парней вроде вас считающих что дизайн - это красота рюшечки радужные кнопки и единороги. Дизайн - вещь функциональная. Вам не нравится кнопка - печально,но это так себе аргумент. Мне например нравится. Приведите доказательства того что Вы в явном большинстве или какие-то соображения что смена дизайна кнопки послужит практической задаче.

Comment: @D-side, но ведь кнопочка =/= весь SO... Короче, я лишь сказал, что кнопка незаметная и что нужно бы сделать её заметнее. Со мной не согласились. Всё это в порядке вещей и никого не должно удивлять)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, слушай, пока что кнопка в плане дизайна находится в стадии "она нажимается - и ладно". Прекрасный функционал и юзабилити  :D Окей? Начнем с этого? А теперь найдем её на странице глазами и посмотрим, как она прекрасно в воздухе висит. ИМХО, не спорю! Но смотрится не от мира сего.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, да я не в большинстве, это уже понятно) Хех, видимо редизайна не будет, но не беда. Сказать-то сказал, обратил внимание. Вот и всё. Закончили. Пойду чай пить.

Comment: Видите ли в чем дело. Тут **много** кнопок. И они выглядят **одинаково**! Почему вы считаете, что одна из них должна быть заметнее других?

Comment: @VostokSisters,  "хреново смотрится" - довольно печальный аргумент для давно работающего продукта. Из серии "поиграйтесь со шрифтами". Хотя бы потому что у юзера уже сложились интерфейсные привычки. UI дизайн - не только вопрос свистелок, но и вопрос функциональности. Если Вы занимаетесь фронтендом и дизайном интерфейсов профессионально, Раскина бы уже прочитали.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну не все одинаково-то... Кнопка "комментировать" и "ответить на собственный вопрос", например. И это не частные случаи же. Вот если, например, сделать "Начать конкурс" такую же синюю, то кнопка бы отражала тот мощный функционал, который она представляет. А отдать репутацию за конкурс как лайк поставить... Ну, не примечательная она-то. Вот и всё.

Comment: @VostokSisters, даже при том что ваш посыл имеет под собой логическое зерно, попробуйте сформулировать его как разработчик а не как заказчик. То есть сформулировать проблему а не решение которое Вы пытаетесь применить. Возможно для решения этой проблемы стоит перекрашивать кнопки, а возможно есть еще решения.

Comment: @alexolut, единороги не при чём, это критика дизайна. Моя думать так: Нарисуй, предложи, не примут - расширением стилизуй и опубликуй нуждающимся.

Comment: @Other, ну это можно. Но уже лень :D

Comment: Вопрос лояльности правления компании к пинанию воздуха сотрудников - это надо решать на другом уровне.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму вот я про это же пытался написать (сформулировать проблему, а не решение), но у вас получилось гораздо лучше.

Answer (score 8):

## Категорически против.

Дело в том, что привлечение внимания работает в две стороны.
*Помогая найти* определённое нечто, оно дополнительно *раздражает* пользователя.

А потому привлечение внимания имеет смысл только для элементов, которые *часто нужны*. Иначе раздражения получается гораздо больше, чем помощи.

Поскольку *мало какие вопросы достойны конкурсов*, получается, что конкретно эта кнопка редко нужна, и дополнительное привлечение к ней внимания не нужно, а для дизайна в целом даже *вредно*.

Comment: Вполне себе может быть и так)